# BlackJack Scoring Program with Errors

Tags: c++

Something is wrong with my code! When I input 5 Cards with the Combo of {"T,Q,J,K,A"} it doesn't tally up the score and instead skips to "Do you want to Play Again." 
I believe its Logic Error but can't seem to find it! Can Anyone Help me with this challenge?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int cardnum, total=0, aceCount=0, i; 
    char face, ans;
    do
    {
    total = 0;
    cout << "How many Cards Do you have in your hands? (Between 2 and 5):\n";
    cin >> cardnum;
    if(cardnum <2 || cardnum > 5)
       {
          cout << "Not a Valid number of cards!\n";
       }
    cout << "Please enter Your Card Values.(2-9 or T, J,Q,K, A): \n";
    for(i=0; i<cardnum; i++)
       {
          cin >> face;
          switch (face)
          {
             case '2' :
                  total+=2;
                  break;
             case '3' :
                  total+=3;
                  break;
             case '4' :
                  total+=4;
                  break;
             case '5' :
                  total+=5;
                  break;
             case '6' :
                  total+=6;
                  break;  
             case '7' :
                  total+=7;
                  break;
             case '8' :
                  total+=8;
                  break;
             case '9' :
                  total+=9;
                  break;
             case 't' :
             case 'j' :
             case 'q' :
             case 'k' :
             case 'T' :
             case 'J' :
             case 'Q' :
             case 'K' :
                  total+=10;
                  break;
             case 'A' :
             case 'a' :
                  total+=11;
                  aceCount++;
          }
      }
      if(total <=21)
      {
         cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<<endl;
      }
      else if(aceCount > 0 && total > 21)
      {
         do
         {
            total-=10;
            aceCount--;
         }while (aceCount > 0 && total >21);

         if(total <=21)
        {
            cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<<endl;
        }
      }
         else if(total > 21)
        {
            cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<< " Which Means You Busted!\n";
        }

    cout << "Do You Wish to Calculate Your Score Again? (Type y OR Y).\n";
    cin >> ans;
    }while(ans == 'y' || ans=='Y');    

    cout << "GOOD BYE! Play NEXT TIME!\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to improve the design of your questions. Start by reading http://www.sscce.org/ & http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and then https://stackoverflow.com/tour & https://stackoverflow.com/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(total <=21)
{
    cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<<endl;
}
```

You have this on both lines so your other desired condition isn't being met.
Just change the second iteration of it to :

```
if(total > 21)
{
    cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<<endl;
}
```

Comment: THis one worked! THank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your indentation, it makes the problem more apparent.

When you are entering the ace processing code in the first else block, the third else block won't be executed. So the score is only printed if it is <= 21. You should do the printing stuff after processing the aces, these two blocks should be indepedent of each other.

Untested, but the code should look something like:

```
  if(aceCount > 0 && total > 21)
  {
     do
     {
        total-=10;
        aceCount--;
     }while (aceCount > 0 && total >21);
  }

  if(total <=21)
        cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<<endl;
  }
  else if(total > 21)
  {
        cout << "Your Total Score is: " << total<< " Which Means You Busted!\n";
  }
```

Comment: I still got error for the "else if(total > 21)" part. Thanks Though